# Why Can't Member Variables Be Used Unqualified In A Lambda If Non-Captured Local Variables Exist?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, shadowing

Simple example:

```
class Foo {
    int x;

    void bar(int x) {
        [this]() -> void {
            x = 6;
        }();
    }
};
```

This doesn't compile on GCC, Clang, MVC, or ICC ([see it live](https://godbolt.org/g/U2l7r3)).  If I change `void bar(int x)` to `void bar(int y)`, or if I change `x = 6;` to `this->x = 6;` then it works fine.

This doesn't make sense to me.  The local variable `x` from the call to `bar` is deliberately not being captured in the lambda.  The only `x` that makes sense is `Foo`'s member variable.

Question: Is this the expected behavior, and iff so, please explain why?

Comment: I guess because the lambda is not a member function of the class.

Comment: Maybe the tag language-lawyer could be appropriate?

Comment: what says the compiler when it fails ?

Comment: @norisknofun The compilers don't seem to be aware of the member variable at all. For details, the specific output was put in the link, for brevity.

Comment: Include the relevant error(s) in the question.

Comment: Include error messages here, not by link.

Comment: in your case, `x=6` is referencing the `x` of `bar(int x)`. And you just not capture it, that's all. I mean : then this ambiguity is seen as an error. But still +1

Comment: It seems the gist of the question is whether the `x` in `x = 6;` should look up to the parameter of `bar`, or the class member.  I can't find where the standard covers this

Comment: @M.M "for purposes of name lookup [...], the compound-statement is considered in the context of the lambda-expression." ?

Comment: Your live error says `warning: private field 'x' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]  int x;` .. I believe that it is because you defined `x` first and then in the `bar()` function you are redefining it, so your first one is not used, therefore the "private field is not used". Try removing the first declaration of `x`

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> For the purpose of name lookup, determining the type and value of the
>   this pointer and for accessing non-static class members, the body of
>   the closure type's function call operator is considered in the context
>   of the lambda-expression.

In the body of the method bar(int x), the token 'x' refers to the argument of the method, NOT to the member of the class.  The member is hidden.
[NOTE this is certainly poor coding practice, but not illegal]

If you were to say `x = 6` where you currently have the lambda definition, you would expect the local variable `x` (i.e. the passed-by-value-argument to the method) to be changed, not the member `x`, right?

Thus the only question is can a local variable be implicitly captured by a lambda?  I'd say the compilers are pretty clear in explaining that it cannot.

cppreference also makes this clear in this statement:

> A variable can be used without being captured if it does not have
>   automatic storage duration (i.e. it is not a local variable or it is
>   static or thread local) or if it is not odr-used in the body of the lambda.

Note: odr-used means you have to know the address of a variable, not just its value.  Assigning a value to a variable counts as odr-using it.

Consider this code:

```
class Foo {
    int george;

    void bar(int washington) {
        int martha = washington;
        washington = 7;
        int jefferson = washington;
        int adams = martha;
        george = 6;
        [this, jefferson]() -> void {
            this->george = 15; // legal because `this` is captured
            jefferson = adams; // legal because jefferson is explicitly
                               // captured, and because adams is not
                               // odr-used, so adams can be captured
                               // implicitly.
            martha = 9; // not legal because it is an odr-use 
                        // of a local variable so martha is not 
                        // implicitly captured.
        }();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you got said:

> error: variable 'x' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified
>
> x = 6;
>
> note: 'x' declared here
>           void bar(int x) {
>                        ^
>   note: lambda expression begins here
>                  this -> void {
>                  ^
>   warning: private field 'x' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
>          int x;

Which led me to thing the problem was with the definition (or more accurate, the *redefinition*) of the variable `x`. You are declaring it both outside `bar()` and as a parameter. The following code did compiled to me (using the live [tool](https://godbolt.org/g/IUnfTI) you showed):

```
class Foo {
    int x;

    void bar() {
        [this]() -> void {
            x = 6;
        }();
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't answer the question. Removing the parameter (or, changing it, as I wrote: `void bar(int y)`) will make it compile—but the question is (1) is this intentional and not a bug and (2) if so, _why_ was that behavior chosen.